# sometimes I will lose commit's signature

Tags: git, gnupg

I often commit work with `-S` argument, but when I check my git log with `git log --show-signature`, some of my works are signed, but some of them are not signed.

I have noticed when I commited, I got some output like this:

```
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: xxxx
4096-bit RSA key, ID xxxx, created 2016-05-21

[master d107770] feat: xxxx
```

but when I check git log, I can't find signature, I don't know why.

my git version is 2.4.8, OS is Ubuntu 14.04.4

Comment: Do you have something like `git config --global commit.gpgsign true` set so it will always prompt to sign commits?

Comment: Thanks @Kris, I have set this to true and it will sign everything even after I pull and rebase code.